# Is "bettern't" an OK word to use?

Tags: word-usage, formality

In the spirit of:

> You can swim, can't you?
>   You should tell the truth, shouldn't you?
>   You'd be crazy to miss out, wouldn't you?

Can I say:

> You better study, bettern't you?

It's [listed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bettern%27t) at wiktionary as '[non-standard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix%3aGlossary#nonstandard)'.

- When would or wouldn't you use this word?
- What can I use instead if I'm trying to be a bit more formal?

Comment: On the one hand you can say almost anything you want if people understand you. However, this is not something you would say.

Comment: It's "You had better study, hadn't you?".  But it still doesn't sound formal.  Maybe "You should study, shouldn't you?" or "You ought to study, oughtn't you?"

Comment: Wiktionary isn't exactly a reliable source. Taking just the randomly-selected decade of the 90s, Google Books records 9 written instances. 8 of them are in the context of faulty language development in toddlers, and one is in an oddball collection of short stories (in large print, which may or may not mean anything), where this contraction is used by the doddery "oldest resident" in a nursing home. Voting to close as "too localised".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I went through the same research/thought process (I feel like creating new words in wiktionary just to see if they catch on). But, though I had never seen or heard of this before, it does seem to sort of exist as a thing to some people. I find it hard to believe but... if kids say it (6 year olds that is) then it has some linguistic justification.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: also, to my American ears, if it sounds like anything, it sounds really British, like  "mayn't I?", something out of CS Lewis child's voice.

Comment: @CamJackson: the kinds of words that usually go in that position are auxiliary or modal verbs 'had', 'have', 'should'. But 'better' is an adjective. It's not common at all; where did you hear or read it or is it a natural thing for you to say? Is there a particular community (a variety like Southern US English or Australian) where you think this is common?

Comment: @Mitch: I wouldn't exactly say it *"exists as a thing to some people"*. The whole point of my comment was to show that it **only** seems to exist as early (3-4 years old) evidence of abnormal language development of a type that attracts the attention of paediatricians. The earlier they become aware of severe defects like this, the more chance they have of managing the problem successfully. I assume OP isn't a native speaker, so these "clinical" considerations don't apply to him. Either that, or he's just being provocative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: 'Mistakes' that show up in children, tend to drive language change. Also, things that are acceptable deviations by native speakers sound really grating and foreign by second-language learners; "bettern't" might turn out to be a native variant, but would sound awful ('ungrammatical') for a non-native speaker.

Comment: @Mitch: Language acquisition is a remarkable process, and there's much we don't know about how it works, but I've never heard any specialists in the area seriously suggest that children's early mistakes are a significant factor in the evolution of language itself. And this particular "mistake" seems to be well-known as an archetypal example of faulty language acquisition, not an emerging feature of mainstream speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Where does language change come from? They're all mistakes to somebody. Anyway, it is well documented that many phenomena of child language correspond directly to patterns of historical change: for example, over generalization of verb endings by regular verbs tend to replace irregular verbs, devoicing of word final voiced phonemes by children can become a language property (e.g. German and Russian).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2427/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-mitch)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I most certainly *am* a native speaker! Now that it's been pointed out to me, the fact that the word "had" is missing from "you better do X" seems obvious, but it sounds quite formal if I say the proper version out loud. Here in Australia I don't think many people (in casual conversation) would say "you had better." It would almost always be shortened to at least "You'd better", and then I think a lot of people have the tendency to drop the "'d" and just say "You better do X.' It may not be correct, but I'd say that "You better X" is quite common here.

Comment: @Mitch (Sorry for double post, but I wanted to notify Mitch and FumbleFingers, and you can only notify one person per comment. See my reply above.) (Also, I agree with Mitch that "You had better" sounds British and formal, keeping in mind that Australian English is much more similar to British English than American English)

Comment: Actually, it is the phrasing at hand, "bettern't", that sounds British to me, not the formalized possible reconstruction. If I were to say "you'd better better put on your coat...", I'd be inclined to say, "...shouldn't you?" or "hadn't you?", except I wouldn't be so inclined given that following items express doubt, and "you'd better" or "you better" don't have that possibility for me.

Comment: @CamJackson: I never mentioned the missing **had / 'd**, which as you say is common in casual speech. I thought you weren't a native speaker because we've had a lot of non-natives here trying to get the hang of contractions, forming patterns like yours and asking if it's okay to write them. The answer is normally *"No, because native speakers never actually **say** that"*. I'm surprised if you've ever heard any adult say *"bettern't"*, but perhaps Australian has diverged from British speech. If not, I don't understand the point of your question.

Comment: @Mitch: I don't know why you think *"bettern't"* sounds British. I don't think it sounds anything because I don't think anyone says it. I think that *"mayn't"*, which sounds somewhat odd/archaic to me, is almost twice as common in American writing than British. But others that sound slightly quaint to me *(mightn't, oughtn't, shan't)* are equally or more common in British, so that doesn't tell me anything. But I'm now baffled as to what the question is all about. Is someone now going to ask why we don't say *"But Mummy! I liken't my greens!"* and have it seriously addressed?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough. You are correct that I've never heard anyone say bettern't, my references to regions was just to say that a lot of people drop the had/'d where I'm from, which it seems is not a regional thing anyway. So, getting back to the original question, I asked it because I've found myself saying "You'd better put on your coat, .." and then thinking, "Oh, um, how do I finish this sentence? Surely bettern't isn't a word?" So the real answer to my question is just that I was missing the "had", so "bettern't" isn't necessary. Everything beyond that is just peripheral discussion.

Comment: @CamJackson: oic. Well you've certainly set the cat among the pigeons! We've even rattled the cage of our friends over at [linguistics.se](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1392/) to see what they've got to say on the matter! Well, the matter of "childish errors" actually, not the matter of why we don't say certain things that we all know we don't, even though there's no obvious structural difference between them and certain other constructions we *do* say. Which I think in the end is an unanswerable question, like "Why do we *say* **W W W** when **world-wide-web** is quicker?"

Comment: @CamJackson: Somewhere in my bloated music library I've got a (bootleg?) live track by [Roy Harper](http://www.royharper.co.uk/) where he mumbles something like *"I could do with a joint right now"*, whereon someone (presumably in the front row) shouts something like *"I'm skinning up!"*. Roy quite clearly replies *"Well, you better 'ad be then, 'adn't you?"*. History does not record the rest of that interaction.

Comment: I'd go with "had you better not", which is very, very awkward.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about, to sound more formal as you said, you say, 'You had better study, hadn't you?'

Comment: Ah yes, 'had' was the extra word I needed!

Answer (score 3):

I've only heard this word widely used in Devon, England. I was living in Plymouth, and people say bettern't you, bettern't he... all the time. You get used to it, and I always consider this is part of the Devon dialect.

edit: I was living in Devon between 1983-1995.

Here is a link to the transcript of a recording from a BBC programme discussing Devon accent and slangs, the original page was archived and recordings deleted, so only the transcript is available.
https://sounds.bl.uk/related-content/TEXTS/021T-C1190X0013XX-0501A0.pdf

Comment: I find this is a pretty useful answer, so I hope you can add some link. Otherwise when it comes to a vote, some might vote to delete it.

Comment: @SConroy Yes, I think it's useful too. My view is that links are desirable but not mandatory, and detail of the person's own experience with a given usage can be valuable information. "Heresay evidence" is admissible, it's just given less weight. To Macbrush: you could improve your answer by adding timeframes - e.g. "I was living in Plymouth 1980-2015". Use the [edit] link. For more guidance on improving your posts, see [answer]. I can also recommend the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: That is absolutely fascinating! I grew up in Australia but half my family is from Bath, Somerset, and my grandparents on that side both spoke with very thick West Country accents their entire lives. I wonder if "bettern't" is buried somewhere deep in my subconscious from hearing them say it in my childhood. Thank you for sharing, @macbrush!

Comment: @fumblefingers I'm not sure if you remember this question from 10 years ago, but given how vehemently you were against "bettern't", you might be interested to know that it *is* in fact, a feature of some West Country dialects. I may well have picked it up from my grandparents.

Answer (score 0):

No, you mayn't say that! in "You better study" the word "had" is upposed to be understood before "better" and, imo, should be there. Rather say "You'd better study, hadn't you?"

Comment: Perhaps this is a cultural/regional thing, but I think "atrociously vulgar and belongs in the stable" is a little harsh... As I mentioned above, "You better X" is a pretty common thing to say in Australia, at least in casual conversation. Obviously you start to run in to problems if you want to put ", ***n't you?" on the end, but in general I don't think it's a huge deal, in itself, to drop the "'d" from "You'd better X."

Comment: Noted. Hadn't I better use a bit of restraint?

Comment: Hah! Yes, you hadn't! :)